# What plant is this that looks like a bush?

Tags: identification, trees, shrubs

My friend saw this plant. What plant is this? Can anyone tell me, please?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Not a bush. Appears to be a species of Ficus.

Comment: This is like a bush on a stick.  This plant has been grafted and/or pruned (headed versus thinned) in an attempt to make it look like a Japanese topiary.  They haven't been working on it much this year.  Any tree can be forced to look like a bush by 'heading'...this particular genus/species is very amenable for manipulation and pruning.  If my guess is correct (I've been wrong a lot lately) the more popular plant is not a hybrid between the two...Hakaro Nishiki looks like this plant but the leaves have white, this light green and pink.  Fun and easy to prune.

Comment: Well its a shrub/tree, but not sure what - any more information please, like where is it growing (country), is there any scent to the leaves, are the leaves soft or spiky to touch, is it deciduous, does it produce flowers?

Comment: Hi! I removed the houseplants tag because this plant is pretty big and it's outside. If you've seen one inside please put the tag back! Thanks!

Comment: Sue, if this is a Ficus, which I think it is, and not a Salix, it can and is grown inside as a House Plant. F. maclellandi "Alli", hybridized in Hawaii is very common in the US, per internet search results.

Comment: @Bamboo Well, it's in India. Other info I cannot give :(

Comment: @stormy light green and yellow!

Comment: @SrihariYamanoor Of course it's not a bush :) I said, "looks like a bush."

Comment: @SrihariYamanoor, I just don't see your ficus.  Yet I also don't see the 'dappled willow' variegation evident on my choice.  The light green is new growth not variegation I THINK.  Grins.

Comment: Yeah, this one needs more research. I was so sure it was Ficus, hah! LoL.

Comment: Can I just say here that the term 'bush' is common usage and just means something (usually something alive) that looks bushy... the plant in the picture is obviously a shrub or a tree, as opposed to a perennial/herbaceous perennial. As for houseplant or not houseplant, its only a houseplant if its grown indoors, whether its a tree, shrub or perennial... I don't think its Ficus and I don't think its Salix integra - but so far, frustratingly,  I can only say what it's not,, rather than what it is! I'd still like to know whether the leaves are soft or stiffish ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Went to the nursery and asked him. This plant is Melaleuca bracteata AKA Golden Bottle Brush. Here are some:

[image]

[image]

Comment: KUDOS, 4K!!  Wow!!  Absolutely!

Answer (score 3):

Like I said, this is a well cared for, and rather interestingly pruned Ficus tree. I am torn between Ficus maclellandii and Ficus longifolia, but if the leaf color is not a photographic aberration, want to say it is Ficus maclellandii.

Edit: Pretty sure my answer is wrong. I will do more research and correct myself.

Comment: Leaf color is not a photographic aberration. I checked both Ficus and neither of them matches this plant. The leaves are really tiny, like a bush.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I am at a loss then. I can even see that classic twisted bark pairing you see in Ficus.

Comment: found it http://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/29438/14009

Answer (score 2):

Here is my guess; Salix integra X Hakaro Nishiki [Salix int.XHakaro Nishiki](https://www.google.com/search?q=salix%20hakuro%20nishiki&rlz=1C1QJDB_en&espv=2&biw=800&bih=385&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjM8q_FmavPAhVS8mMKHTviB-4Q7AkIKA#imgrc=aPS8faXB6BKYWM%3Ahttp://)

Comment: This is closer, but still a lot different.

Comment: 4K, if you know what this is put us out of our misery!  I have been looking for straight S. integra and just green, not dappled.  Sigh.  I'm waitin' for an answer!

Comment: I will see if I can find this plant. I will ask for a Hindi name next time I visit the nursery, if they have one.

Comment: found it! http://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/29438/14009